# Different GUI on phone and tablet, but same app

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, android-screen-support

I have to write an app for tablet and for phones too. The two app has the same functionality, but they have absolute different GUI.

For example the phone have 2 button on the main screen, but the tablet going to have 5, because we would like to use the space what we have. I know, I˜m able to define different layouts, depends on dpi, but how should I handle the layout-s in the Activiies? I think, to use if(sdkVersion >=11) bla..bla... is not will works through the hole code and the hole project! Is this the situation where I have to use multiple application support ?

readed articles:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html

I don`t understand how should I handle this problem... please if you able help , thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your tablet layouts in `res/layout-large/`. Put your phone layouts in `res/layout/`. Name them the same. Your activities will load the right ones based upon the device they run on. When you call `findViewById()` to retrieve the extra buttons, and see that you get `null` back, ignore them.

You may need additional layouts in places like `res/layout-large-land/` (landscape for tablets), `res/layout-xlarge/` (if you want to handle 10+" tablets differently than stuff in the 5-9" range), `res/layout-small/` (if you want to handle <3" screens), etc.

Comment: Hello CommonsWare!
Thanks for your comment, but "When you call findViewById() to retrieve the extra buttons, and see that you get null back, ignore them." is what I would like to dismiss. because we are going to start a large project with a lot of activities you know, and always doing an if(findViewById(R.id.btn7)==null) is makes the code unreadable so easily .... I looking for an elegant solution :)

Comment: @Karoly: "and always doing an if(findViewById(R.id.btn7)==null) is makes the code unreadable so easily" -- what "always"? Use one of those fancy Java things called "data members" to hold the widget or a `boolean`. Or reorganize your UI to take advantage of fragments, so on phones you are using one fragment per activity, yet your main activity loads a layout that brings up two fragments.

Comment: but as I see the fregments comes with API level 11. For tablets, okay, but how can I use fregments if we want to run the app on phones (2.1,2.2.2.3) and talbet too

Comment: @Karoly: Fragments are part of the Android Compatibility Library and therefore are available back to Android 1.6.