# How can I create a project for phones and tablets in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, tablet

How can I create a project in Android Studio for phones and tablets, where the APK on the Play Store is the same for both?

I am using build variants with build flavors, but there are two APKs for every device.

Comment: By default your `.apk` will work on both. The question is how it will look like if don't design `layout`s for both separately.

Comment: yes, my layouts they are created separate every one, and values for every device, but the activity's they are created in build flavor main or build phone or buid tablet.

Comment: The logic shouldn't be the matter, if your app hasn't some specific behavior... hm... like "if you use tablet - you don't need to register", so you don't have anything to worry about. Main problem in this question - `layout`s. If you say there is everything ok, so just upload it. Or do you have anything specific in logic targeted exactly to the phone or tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can just approximate if it's a tablet or not by checking the screendimension. If the app uses XLARGE or LARGE display dimensions, it could be a tablet or a "big" phone.

You can get informations about that with something like this:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE 
|| getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
    //doSomething
}
```

You can test which of these ones is the better one for you.

**more reference:**

[Designing Android apps for tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938163/designing-android-apps-for-tablets/18036084#18036084)

[Different GUI on phone and tablet, but same app problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456087/different-gui-on-phone-and-tablet-but-same-app-problem)